# How to create cross-app library in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some problem with figouring out how to solve this.
I need to build some cross app library in ReactJs. Something like jQuery but simpler. Library will be adding HTML element to the DOM of the page on which the library was added.
The case is that when for example page with implemented library is simple static page written in HTML only without ReactJs on it the library need to add React and this missing HTML element.
Finally the library need to be hosted on some CDN not as npm package.

Any idea how to make it work? Is it possible to do?
Any ideas are welcome

Comment: Hello) Well, seems like any other library. You can add Id to the element you want to add HTML inside and initialize library(for example `initMyLibrary('#elementId')`) on `componentDIdMount`.

Comment: How to figure out if I need to add React and React DOM scripts?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. If you need to use React you importing these packages. If you want to use the external\your custom library you need to use react component lifecycles.  See docs https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html